# updating a specific chunk with the help of chunk_id in the FAISS

Tags: vector, store, chunks, faiss

I have a set of PDFs which are stored in the FAISS vector store. Now I am able to visualize then in the form of data frame, but I want to updated a specific chunk content with the help of the chunk_id.
Is it possible to do?

Looked for the specific API in many websites and tutorials but was not able to get it.